# Using the RESTful interface to Google's AJAX Search API for "Did you mean"?

Tags: python, ajax, search, rest

Is it possible to get spelling/search suggestions (i.e. "Did you mean") via the RESTful interface to Google's AJAX search API? I'm trying to access this from Python, though the URL query syntax is all I really need.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a good RESTful API for spelling suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Google AJAX API don't have a spelling check feature see [this](https://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api/browse_thread/thread/61eb608918f00632/ee794142dbf87046?lnk=raot), you can use the [SOAP service](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html#1_3) but i think it's no longer available .

at last you can look at yahoo API they have a feature for [spelling check](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/web/V1/spellingSuggestion.html).

**EDIT :** check this maybe it can help you:

```
import httplib
import xml.dom.minidom

data = """
<spellrequest textalreadyclipped="0" ignoredups="0" ignoredigits="1" ignoreallcaps="1">
    <text> %s </text>
</spellrequest>
"""

word_to_spell = "gooooooogle"

con = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.google.com")
con.request("POST", "/tbproxy/spell?lang=en", data % word_to_spell)
response = con.getresponse()

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(response.read())
dom_data = dom.getElementsByTagName('spellresult')[0]

for child_node in dom_data.childNodes:
    result = child_node.firstChild.data.split()

print result
```

Comment: I'm looking into options available from other search engines. I'll try this code sample out as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you're just looking for spelling suggestions you might want to check out something like Wordnik: http://docs.wordnik.com/api/methods

Comment: I'm actually looking for hit counts as well as spelling suggestions, so that doesn't quite do the job, but thanks.